# Set Title to SlidingMenu in Android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Is there a way I can add title to the list that I populate in Sliding Menu(jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu)? If yes, How do I do it? or do I have to use my custom view to set the title? Please link an example if you have one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sliding Menu library just allows a view to be specified when "sliding" in. It is up to you to put titles in there if that's what you need.

Comment: Okie... I just wanted to know, if I can set the title for the view and that title remains constant when we use the scroll feature of the sliding menu. Would be nice to have a feature to set the title (i think). Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: If you use a fragment in the sliding view then you can expose a method within that fragment to set the title, which would be available to all activities that used the sliding menu.